# UITableView editing selection doesnt work for few cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I'm setting it to the editing option to select the cells. This works fine for most of the cells. But irractically, it doesnt work for some row or the other. Is this a iOS7 bug or something? Is there something I can do? I'm not making changes to the selection other than the color change using:

```
[self.tableView setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"multiselectCheckmarkColor"];
```

As shown below, fell cells can be selected. Others cannot.

[image]

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` are both called. But the tick mark doesn't appear. Please help.

Comment: Interesting. Does it work if you do not change the color?

Comment: Yes. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, the color change has nothing to do with the problem.

Return the right value from `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`. Please note that this will not be called if you set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to `YES`.

You can get all selected index paths via `indexPathsForSelectedRows`.

Comment: If I set allowsMultpleSelectionDuringEditing to NO, the bubbles for selection are missing. I'm tracking the selected index paths using didselect and didDeselect. Are you saying I'll need to create a custom cell with a button and track using indexPathsForSelectedRows?

Comment: Subclassing has nothing to do with `indexPathsForSelectedRows`, which is a table view method. I recently implemented a similar controller with custom cells without editing mode.

Comment: I found the solution. But not the best way though. When I set a background color to the cell while selection, everything works fine.